# Помогите функцию перевести в stream api

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

**Есть матрица:**

```
List<ArrayList<Double>> matr;
```

**требуется в матрице найти среднее значение, без стримов я это делаю так:**

```
 public Double averageMatr() {
        Double sum=0.0;
        for (ArrayList<Double> list : matr) {
            for (Double item : list) {
                sum+=item;
            }

        }
        return sum/matr.size()*countColumn;
    }
```

**Подскажите как можно этот цикл записать в стримах?**

**Пытался сделать вот так:**

```
public Double averageMatr() {
        Double sum=0.0;
        for (ArrayList<Double> list : matr) {
           sum+= list.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
        }
        return sum/matr.size();
    }
```

**Но так получается неверный результат. со строк находится среднее значение, и дальше берется среднее значение из средних значений. То есть неверно.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается очень просто с помощью метода `Stream.flatMap`:

```
matr.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).mapToDouble(d -> d).average()
```

Comment: большое спасибо:) а как работает flatMap не подскажите?

Comment: @Санаев `flatMap` по сути делает из стрима стримов один плоский стрим.

Comment: круто. то что я искал.